# Android - detect if speakers are playing audio programmatically

Tags: android, audio

I'm working on a diagnosis app for android, I want to test whether the speakers are working fine or not. I thought the way to do this is to play a sound and check whether the speakers are playing the audio or not. I looked for code but didn't find anything useful. How can this be achieved in android? Is there a better way to do the same thing?

Comment: Do you want to check if your speaker is working or not?

Comment: @Nabin Khadka Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: One way is to play sound and let the user confirm if he/she hears something. But the device itself, I doubt that can be done.